# Write item in a ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview, javabeans, listitem

I'm developing an app. In my app I'm stored some information in a class named Promo in which I defined 4 strings and I made the 4 getter and setters. Then I made another class named Promotions in which I defined an array of Promo.
To store data in the Promo model I'm doing so:

```
 Promo promo = new Promo();
            promo.setName("Promozione");
            promo.setDescription("La promozione può essere spesa");
            promo.setDate("29 Lug 2013");
            promo.setImgUrl("http://www.pensando.it/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/coupon.jpg");
```

Now in another intent I will to show the field name in a ListView and when I click on the item of this ListView I will load another intent in which I will show the details of this promo.
To write the name in the ListView I made a method in which I want to read the data from the array Promo and I will to display the name of promotions in my list item. To do that I made a ListAdapter and I pass it the class and the array of promotions, but it says me that I should initialized the array promotions. I will post here the code I'm trying to use to display this informations:

**Method loadDataFromModel**

```
private void loadDataFromModel() {

    lvTitle = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTitle);

    final Promotions[] promotions;

    ListAdapter laTitle = new ListAdapter(ArchiveActivity2.class, promotions);
    lvTitle.setAdapter(laTitle);

    lvTitle.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    });


}
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import it.bitmama.InteracTv.R;
import it.bitmama.InteracTv.model.Promotions;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Promotions> {
    public  ListAdapter(Context context, Promotions[] promotions) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.tvTitle, promotions);
    }
}
```

I will post too the two class that I'm using like models:

**Promo.java**

```
public class Promo {
    String name;
    String description;
    String imgUrl;
    String date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.toString();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**Promotions.java**

```
public class Promotions {
    public Promo[] promotions;
}
```

Now I hope you know what's I'm trying to do, I need your help to display correctly this informations.
Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I want to know if it's right the code I wrote and how to display this informations in a ListView, because it says me that I should initialize `final Promotions[] promotions;`, but how I can initialize this object if I don't know the dimension of the array Promo?

Comment: use an ArrayList instead

Comment: You mean that in the Promotions.java, I should define an ArrayList of Promo? Like so: `public ArrayList<Promo> promotions`. I understand well? The other part of my code is correct?

Comment: you are passing null as a list, initialize array or use ArrayList as blackbelt suggested. Another thing is final Promotions[] promotions is scoped within the method so if you run method again you will have another "final" null.

Comment: I can not understand why do you subclassed ArrayAdapterm

Comment: Can you write an answer in which you show me your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create adapter:

   private ArrayAdapter mAdapter;

   private void loadDataFromModel() {

   ```
   lvTitle = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTitle);
   ArrayList<Promo> list = new ArrayList<Promo>();


   ArrayAdapter mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext() , R.id.lvTitle, list);
   lvTitle.setAdapter(mAdapter);

   lvTitle.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       }
   });
   ```

   }
2. modify members of adapter:

   void onNewMember(Promo promo) {

   ```
   mAdapter.add(promo);
   ```

   }

You may set members of array list before injection in loadDataFromModel()

```
Promo promo = new Promo();
... set properties as wanted
list.add(promo)
```

Comment: I've just the last question, where I should insert the method to add a new member in my mAdapter? I should insert it in the class in which I wrote the `loadDataFromModel` method?
I inserted the code you posted at the begin of your post and it says me: "Method call expected", I wrote it so `ArrayAdapter mAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.id.lvTitle, list);`

Comment: this depends where you get your data from, you can set members of ArrayList before you inject it into adapter.

Comment: I'm getting mad about this! I copied the code you wrote in here and the stupid Android Studio says me this 2 issue:
- for this: `ArrayAdapter mAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.id.lvTitle, list);` it says "Method call expected".
- for this: `lvTitle.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                    int position, long arg) {
}
});` says "setOnClickListener in AdapterView cannot be applied to android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener"
What's wrong now??

Comment: my bad, it should be ArrayAdapter mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, R.id.lvTitle, list);

Comment: For the second is my bad... I wrote `setOnClickListener` and I should wrote `setOnItemClickListener`, until now my issues is solved, now I've to try the app and I'm scared about that :D

Comment: use setOnItemClickListener not setOnClickListener and instance of listener is OnItemClickListener not OnClickListener,